# properties of square matrix to power n

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

I find something confusing. Consider the matrix 
$\begin{bmatrix}a & -b \\ b & a\end{bmatrix}$, we can find $\begin{bmatrix}a & -b \\ b & a\end{bmatrix}^{k} = \begin{bmatrix}Re(\lambda^k) & -Im(\lambda^k) \\ Im(\lambda^k) & Re(\lambda^k)\end{bmatrix}$ by induction, where $\lambda = a + ib$.

I am a little confused about this interesting result. Is there any theorem behind such phenomenon?

Comment: yes, there is more theory behind it (not too hard) but just requires some prep work/terminology. The basic idea is that there is a bijective correspondence between complex numbers $ \lambda = a+ib$ and $2 \times 2$ real matrices of the special form $\xi = \begin{pmatrix} a& -b \\ b & a\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \text{Re}(\lambda)& -\text{Im}(\lambda) \\ \text{Im}(\lambda) & \text{Re}(\lambda)\end{pmatrix}$. So, rather than computing the matrix power $\xi^k$, you simply look at the associated complex number $\lambda$, compute its $k$th power $\lambda^k$, and then "convert" back to a matrix

Answer (score 1):

Yes. We have an  injective $\mathbb{R}$-algebra morphism $$f:\lambda =a+ib\in\mathbb{C}\mapsto \pmatrix{a & -b\cr b & \phantom{-}a}\in M_2(\mathbb{R}).$$

Injectivity is clear, and the fact that $f$ respects addition and multiplication, as well as $\mathbb{R}$-linearity, are just simple computations.

In particular, we have $f(\lambda^k)=f(\lambda)^k$ for all $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ and all $k\geq 0$.
Using the definition of $f$, this is exactly the equality you seek.

Answer (score 0):

If you write $a+bi$ as $\rho\bigl(\cos(\theta)+\sin(\theta)i\bigr)$ (with $\rho\geqslant0$), then$$\begin{bmatrix}a&-b\\b&a\end{bmatrix}=\rho\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{bmatrix}$$and therefore$$\begin{bmatrix}a&-b\\b&a\end{bmatrix}^k=\rho^k\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{bmatrix}^k=\rho^k\begin{bmatrix}\cos(k\theta)&-\sin(k\theta)\\\sin(k\theta)&\cos(k\theta)\end{bmatrix}.$$Now, use the fact that $(a+bi)^k=\rho^k\bigl(\cos(k\theta)+\sin(k\theta)i\bigr)$.